# How to implement multi select on blazor when search for server name text?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly

I work on blazor server side . I face issue I can't apply `.multiselect();` multi select based on web API ?

I need multi select as server1,server2 text display when search .

when select first time then server1 and second time select server2 then `server1,server2`

what I try as below :

1 - create model servers

```
public class ServerNames
    {
        [Key]
        public int ServerID { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Server name is required")]
        public string Server_Name{ get; set; }
    }
```

2 - Implement service

```
List<ServerNames> GetSimilarServers(string searchText);

    
public List<ServerNames> GetSimilarServers(string searchText)
        {
            var serverNames = _context.ServerNames.Where(p => p.Server_Name.Contains(searchText)).ToList();

            return serverNames;
        }
```

3 - call service on controller web api

```
[HttpGet]
            [Route("/api/ServerNames/GetSimilarServers/{searchText}")]
            public JsonResult GetSimilarServers(string searchText)
            {
                var serversName =  _IserverNamesService.GetSimilarServers(searchText);
    
                return new JsonResult(serversName);
            }
```

4 - on `server.razor` component I call web API make search filter

```
@code 
{
private List<ServerNames> SimilarServers{ get; set; }
public  async Task<ServerNames> DisplayListServer(string SearchText)
    {
       
        var serversLists = await GetSimilarServers(SearchText);

        SimilarServers = serversLists.ToList();
       
    }
public async Task<IEnumerable<ServerNames>> GetSimilarServers(string searchText)
    {
        HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
        var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(config["API_URL"] + "ServerNames/GetSimilarServers/" + searchText + "");
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var result = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<ServerNames[]>(await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync(), new JsonSerializerOptions() { PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true });
            return result;
        }
        else
        {
            return null; //handle the response that was not successful here.
        }
    }
}
```

what i try is

```
<select class="form-select">
                                        @if (serversname.Any())
                                        {
                                            
                                        
                                        <option value="0">--Select--</option>
                                        @foreach (var serv in SimilarServers)
                                        {
                                            <option value="@serv.serverID">
                                                @serv.server_Name
                                            </option>
                                        }
                                        }

                                    </select>
```

How to make select accept multi selection text as server1,server2,etc

**Updated post**

I need drop down accept multiple select with check box
so if i check box server 1 and server 2 then server1,server2

see image below

[image: drop down with multi select check box]

Comment: How long is the server list?

Comment: exactly 200 server is number of server exactly can reach

Comment: if any thing not clear let me now please

Comment: Why do some code parts missing like the `multiple` attribute on the `select` element? It is not really clear whether you are asking for a complete solution or just asking for help regarding a specific part of the code.

Comment: my solution i need is drop down display with multi selection with check box so if i check server1 and server 2 then server1,server2

Comment: let me know if my result i need not gotted

Comment: What happens when your search results exclude a server that the user has already selected?  How do you handle that?  Creating a UX that works is not as simple as you first imagine.  For this solution you almost certainly need two controls: a list of selected items, and a list of items you can select/deselect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With 200 items to select you don't need to worry about getting the filtered list on each keystroke.  Get the lot and use a datalist.

Here's a composite control of mine that is close to what I think you want:

```cs
@inject CountryPresenter _presenter
@using System.Linq.Expressions;
@using System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis;

<div class="col-12 col col-lg-4 mb-3">
    <label class="form-labelsm small">@this.Label</label>
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text"
               list="@listId"
               @bind:get=_currentValue
               @bind:set=this.SetValue
               placeholder="@this.PlaceholderText"
               @attributes=this.AdditionalAttributes />
        <button class="btn btn-success" disabled="@_isNotCurrentValue" @onclick=AddCurrentValue>Add</button>
    </div>
</div>
<datalist id="@listId">
    @foreach (var option in OptionItems)
    {
        <option>@option</option>
    }

</datalist>

@foreach (var item in _selectedItems)
{
    <div class="m-1 p-1">
        <span class="badge bg-danger" style="cursor:pointer;" @onclick="() => this.DeleteItem(item)">Remove</span>
        <span class="ms-4">@item</span>
    </div>
}

@code {
    [CascadingParameter] private EditContext? _editContext { get; set; }

    [Parameter] public string[]? Value { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public EventCallback<string[]?> ValueChanged { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public Expression<Func<string[]>>? ValueExpression { get; set; }

    [Parameter, EditorRequired] public IEnumerable<string> OptionItems { get; set; } = default!;

    [Parameter(CaptureUnmatchedValues = true)] public IReadOnlyDictionary<string, object>? AdditionalAttributes { get; set; }
    [Parameter, EditorRequired] public string Label { get; set; } = "No Label";
    [Parameter] public string PlaceholderText { get; set; } = "Select a Value";

    private List<string> _selectedItems = new();
    private readonly string listId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    private string? _currentValue;
    private bool _isNotCurrentValue => _currentValue is null;

    public override Task SetParametersAsync(ParameterView parameters)
    {
        parameters.SetParameterProperties(this);
        _selectedItems = new();

        if (this.Value is not null)
            _selectedItems = this.Value.ToList();

        return base.SetParametersAsync(parameters);
    }
    private void SetValue(string value)
    => _currentValue = value;

    private void DeleteItem(string value)
    {
        if (_selectedItems.Any(item => item.Equals(value)))
        {
            _selectedItems.Remove(value);
            this.NotifyEditContext();
            ValueChanged.InvokeAsync(_selectedItems.ToArray());
        }
    }

    private void AddCurrentValue()
    {
        if (_currentValue is not null && !_selectedItems.Any(item => item.Equals(_currentValue)))
        {
            _selectedItems.Add(_currentValue);
            _currentValue = null;
            this.NotifyEditContext();
            ValueChanged.InvokeAsync(_selectedItems.ToArray());
        }
    }

    private void NotifyEditContext()
    {
        if (ValueExpression is not null && _editContext is not null)
        {
            var fi = FieldIdentifier.Create(ValueExpression);
            _editContext?.NotifyFieldChanged(fi);
        }
    }
}
```

A demo page

```cs
@page "/"
@inject CountryPresenter _countryPresenter
<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

<div class="mb-3">Welcome to your new app.</div>


<MultiSelectControl class="form-control"
                    Label="Select Countries"
                    @bind-Value=_countryPresenter.SelectedCountries
                    OptionItems=_countryPresenter.CountryList />

@*Display the data*@
<div class="bg-dark text-white p-2 mt-5">
    @if (_countryPresenter.SelectedCountries is not null)
    {
        @foreach (var item in _countryPresenter.SelectedCountries)
        {
            <pre>@item</pre>
        }
    }
</div>

@code {
    protected async override Task OnInitializedAsync()
        => await _countryPresenter.LoadingTask;
}
```

The presentation service that manages the data.

```cs
public class CountryPresenter
{
    private CountryDataProvider _countryProvider;

    public string[]? SelectedCountries { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<string> CountryList = Enumerable.Empty<string>();

    public Task LoadingTask { get; private set; } = Task.CompletedTask;

    public CountryPresenter(CountryDataProvider countryProvider)
    {
        _countryProvider = countryProvider;
        this.LoadingTask = this.LoadCountriesAsync();
    }

    private async Task LoadCountriesAsync()
        => this.CountryList = await _countryProvider.GetCountyListAsync();
}
```

And the country data provider for our data.

```cs
public class CountryDataProvider
{
    public async ValueTask<IEnumerable<string>> GetCountyListAsync()
    {
        //Dummy a async DB Call
        await Task.Yield();

        return CountryArray.AsEnumerable();
    }

    public static string[] CountryArray = new string[]
    {
            "Afghanistan", "Albania", "Algeria", "American Samoa", "Andorra", "Angola", "Anguilla", "Antarctica", "Antigua and Barbuda",
            "Argentina", "Armenia", "Aruba", "Australia", "Austria", "Azerbaijan", "Bahamas",  "Bahrain", "Bangladesh",
            "Barbados", "Belarus", "Belgium", "Belize", "Benin", "Bermuda", "Bhutan", "Bolivia", "Bosnia and Herzegovina",
            "Botswana", "Bouvet Island", "Brazil", "British Indian Ocean Territory",  "Brunei Darussalam", "Bulgaria", "Burkina Faso",
            "Burundi", "Cambodia", "Cameroon", "Canada", "Cape Verde", "Cayman Islands", "Central African Republic", "Chad", "Chile",
            "China", "Christmas Island", "Cocos (Keeling) Islands", "Colombia", "Comoros", "Congo", "Congo, the Democratic Republic of the",
            "Cook Islands", "Costa Rica", "Cote D'Ivoire", "Croatia", "Cuba", "Cyprus", "Czech Republic", "Denmark", "Djibouti",
            "Dominica", "Dominican Republic", "Ecuador", "Egypt", "El Salvador", "Equatorial Guinea", "Eritrea", "Estonia", "Ethiopia",
            "Falkland Islands (Malvinas)", "Faroe Islands", "Fiji", "Finland", "France", "French Guiana", "French Polynesia", "French Southern Territories",
            "Gabon", "Gambia", "Georgia", "Germany", "Ghana", "Gibraltar", "Greece", "Greenland", "Grenada", "Guadeloupe", "Guam", "Guatemala",
            "Guinea", "Guinea-Bissau", "Guyana", "Haiti", "Heard Island and Mcdonald Islands", "Holy See (Vatican City State)", "Honduras",
            "Hong Kong", "Hungary", "Iceland", "India", "Indonesia", "Iran, Islamic Republic of", "Iraq", "Ireland", "Israel", "Italy", "Jamaica",
            "Japan", "Jordan", "Kazakhstan", "Kenya", "Kiribati", "Korea, Democratic People's Republic of", "Korea, Republic of", "Kuwait",
            "Kyrgyzstan", "Lao People's Democratic Republic", "Latvia", "Lebanon", "Lesotho", "Liberia", "Libyan Arab Jamahiriya", "Liechtenstein",
            "Lithuania", "Luxembourg", "Macao", "Macedonia, the Former Yugoslav Republic of", "Madagascar", "Malawi", "Malaysia", "Maldives",
            "Mali", "Malta", "Marshall Islands", "Martinique", "Mauritania", "Mauritius", "Mayotte", "Mexico", "Micronesia, Federated States of",
            "Moldova, Republic of", "Monaco", "Mongolia", "Montserrat", "Morocco", "Mozambique", "Myanmar", "Namibia", "Nauru", "Nepal",
            "Netherlands", "Netherlands Antilles", "New Caledonia", "New Zealand", "Nicaragua", "Niger", "Nigeria", "Niue", "Norfolk Island",
            "Northern Mariana Islands", "Norway", "Oman", "Pakistan", "Palau", "Palestinian Territory, Occupied", "Panama", "Papua New Guinea",
            "Paraguay", "Peru", "Philippines", "Pitcairn", "Poland", "Portugal", "Puerto Rico", "Qatar", "Reunion", "Romania", "Russian Federation",
            "Rwanda", "Saint Helena", "Saint Kitts and Nevis", "Saint Lucia", "Saint Pierre and Miquelon", "Saint Vincent and the Grenadines",
            "Samoa",  "San Marino", "Sao Tome and Principe", "Saudi Arabia", "Senegal", "Serbia and Montenegro", "Seychelles", "Sierra Leone",
            "Singapore", "Slovakia", "Slovenia", "Solomon Islands", "Somalia", "South Africa", "South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands",
            "Spain", "Sri Lanka", "Sudan", "Suriname", "Svalbard and Jan Mayen", "Swaziland", "Sweden", "Switzerland", "Syrian Arab Republic",
            "Taiwan, Province of China", "Tajikistan", "Tanzania, United Republic of", "Thailand", "Timor-Leste", "Togo", "Tokelau",
            "Tonga", "Trinidad and Tobago", "Tunisia", "Turkey", "Turkmenistan", "Turks and Caicos Islands", "Tuvalu", "Uganda", "Ukraine",
            "United Arab Emirates", "United Kingdom", "United States", "United States Minor Outlying Islands", "Uruguay", "Uzbekistan", "Vanuatu",
            "Venezuela", "Viet Nam", "Virgin Islands, British",   "Virgin Islands, US", "Wallis and Futuna", "Western Sahara",
            "Yemen", "Zambia", "Zimbabwe",
    };
}
```

Service registration:

```cs
builder.Services.AddScoped<CountryDataProvider>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<CountryPresenter>();
```