# Why is null displayed instead of the values selected from a multi selection input?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, c#-4.0, blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly

I working on blazor server side . I face issue I can't get values selected on razor page

I can select data and fill on control select 2 but can't get values selected separated by comma  outside on `<p> tag`.

I put break point on event `OnSelectedValuesChanged` it not catch or hit when debug .

**Issue selected value for items selected display null**

custom control I made it (Select2MultiSelect.razor)

```
<select id="@ElementId" @onchange="OnSelectionChanged">
    @foreach (var option in Options)
    {
        <option value="@option.serverID">@option.server_Name</option>
    }
</select>

@code {
    [Parameter] public string ElementId { get; set; } = "select2_" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N");
    [Parameter] public List<SelectedServers> Options { get; set; } = new();
    [Parameter] public List<string> SelectedValues { get; set; } = new();
    [Parameter] public EventCallback<List<string>> SelectedValuesChanged { get; set; }

    private async Task OnSelectionChanged(ChangeEventArgs args)
    {
        SelectedValues = await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<List<string>>("select2Interop.getSelectedValues", ElementId);
        await SelectedValuesChanged.InvokeAsync(SelectedValues);
    }

    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
        {
            await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("select2Interop.initializeSelect2", ElementId);
            await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("select2Interop.setSelectedValues", ElementId, SelectedValues);
        }
    }
```

JS file I use it

Select2JsInterop.js

```
window.select2Interop = {
    initializeSelect2: function (elementId) {
        $('#' + elementId).select2({
            width: '100%',
            multiple: true
        });
    },

    getSelectedValues: function (elementId) {
        return $('#' + elementId).val();
    },

    setSelectedValues: function (elementId, values) {
        $('#' + elementId).val(values).trigger('change');
    }
};
```

on _host file i use

```
<script src="~/assets/js/select2jsinterop.js"></script>
    <script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>
```

on UI I use control as below

```
 <Select2MultiSelect Options="@SimilarServers" SelectedValues="@selectedValues" SelectedValuesChanged="OnSelectedValuesChanged" />
                                        <p>Selected values: @string.Join(", ", @selectedValues)</p>
private void OnSelectedValuesChanged(List<string> newSelectedValues)
    {
        selectedValues = newSelectedValues;
        
    }
private List<SelectedServers> SimilarServers = new()
    {
        new SelectedServers { serverID = 1, server_Name = "atapa222" },
        new SelectedServers { serverID = 2, server_Name = "linuxdata2" }
        
    };
public class SelectedServers
    {
        public int serverID { get; set; }
        public string server_Name { get; set; }
    }
```

selected value display null why and how to solve it ?

[image: selected value display null]

**Updated post**

why custom control i make get null value on selected value

this is libraries i use it

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>

<!-- Select2 CSS -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<!-- Select2 JS -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Where is `selectedValues` defined and where is it used to display something? I cannot see the related code in your question.

Comment: selected value defined on event OnSelectedValuesChanged and this event must fire when change on select2 as add item like that and event defined for select2 as SelectedValuesChanged="OnSelectedValuesChanged"

Comment: Did you try to set a breakpoint in `OnSelectedValuesChanged` to see when it is called and what is passed to it?

Comment: yes not hit or catch it not detect it so why this not detect

Comment: When `OnSelectedValuesChanged` is not hit then either `OnSelectionChanged` is not called or the `await` call in this method never returns or breaks. Please verify this by using additional breakpoints, having a look at the debug console / browser development console.

Comment: can you pleas tell me how to show or write console.log(????) can you please

Comment: `console.log()` is a JS call. I was referring to the browser development console where you can analyze and debug JS code, in Chrome it is called DevTools, see https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/open/

Comment: thanks for support but i need to know the reason of issue why selected value on custom component get null value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're seriously overcomplicating this.  You don't need any JS or custom  control to do what you've asked in the question.

Blazor supports using a multi select.  You can code what you've shown with the standard `InputSelect` like this:

```cs
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

<InputSelect class="form-select" @bind-Value=selectedValues>
    @foreach (var option in SimilarServers)
    {
        <option value="@option.serverID.ToString()">@option.server_Name</option>
    }
</InputSelect>

<div class="bg-dark text-white m-2 p-1">
    <pre>@GetSelectedValues()</pre>
</div>

@code {
    private int[] selectedValues = new int[] { };

    private string GetSelectedValues()
    {
        List<string> list = new();
        foreach (int x in selectedValues)
        {
            var server = this.SimilarServers.FirstOrDefault(item => item.serverID == x);
            if (server is not null)
                list.Add(server.server_Name);
        }
        return string.Join(", ", list);
    }

    private List<SelectedServers> SimilarServers = new()
    {
        new SelectedServers { serverID = 1, server_Name = "atapa222" },
        new SelectedServers { serverID = 2, server_Name = "linuxdata2" },
        new SelectedServers { serverID = 3, server_Name = "London" },
        new SelectedServers { serverID = 4, server_Name = "Paris" },
        new SelectedServers { serverID = 5, server_Name = "New York" },
    };
}
```

Note I'm binding onto the `ServerID` - as you are doing in the question - so get a comma separated list of server names by doing a look up for all the selected `ServerID` values.

[image]

Comment: Don't you need a `multiple` flag somewhere?  (Oh nvm I googled it, the bind is smart enough to do it)

Comment: @Bennyboy1973 - not if you use `InputSelect`.   It detects if `TValue` is an array -    `_isMultipleSelect = typeof(TValue).IsArray;` - and then sets up the appropriate attributes and bindings.  - see https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/03e670f9854651b9995d57f8e87cef16022e739a/src/Components/Web/src/Forms/InputSelect.cs#L46

Comment: Yeah I saw.  I'm curious if it does any other neat stuff like paging, because 200 potential items in a selection dropdown is going to be about 180 too many.

Comment: @Bennyboy1973 - different solution.  If you need such a control ask a question and I'll show you what I would do.

Comment: ty for the offer, but I can do that already.  You answered the OP nicely, but I'm wondering if a dropdown is really his best option.  I know that scrolling down a long droplist annoys me in age selection because I'm not so young anymore-- but I'm nowhere 200 years old. :)

Comment: @Bennyboy1973 - The OP has already asked a similar question here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76019461/how-to-implement-multi-select-on-blazor-when-search-for-server-name-text/76043410#76043410 - and I've given him a different answer.  He hasn't replied to either answer, so I'm signing off from the questions!

Comment: Yeah, that's annoying.  Pearls before swine I think!